# ActionScript 3 using sortOn with object y value

Tags: actionscript

How can I make sortOn accept the value of my movieClip's Y axis, like this:

`array.sortOn("movieClip".y,Array.NUMERIC)`

It works if I put the value into `["y"]`, like so: `array.sortOn("y",Array.NUMERIC)` but I'd prefer not to.

Comment: if you would like to hand over the value "y", you can do that with a getter/setter functionality. That should work. But other question, how do you defined your array, and have you declared the values there ? https://help.adobe.com/de_DE/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#sortOn() read the manual ;)

Comment: The **array.sortOn("y", Array.NUMERIC);** line is a perfectly correct way of sorting a list of **MovieClip**s by their Y-coordinate.